# can I give SQL Server database name with hyphen like abc-123?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a sql server database with name of `abc-123`, in that I created a table Emp, when I run like

```
select * from abc-123.emp;
```

I am getting the results.
But when I am trying to grant some privilege to the user I unable to do that, *getting syntax error near hyphen .*

will any one help me?

Comment: Do you have to use -? Underscores '_' are more commonly used.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Make sure you are escaping the names with [] (T-SQL) or "" (ANSI SQL).  You are using non-standard naming.

```
-- Sample select
SELECT * FROM [abc-123].[dbo].[emp];
SELECT * FROM "abc-123"."dbo"."emp";
```

1 - Can you send me an example of the grant TSQL?  If you are doing the action from SSMS, right click and script the code.

2 - Here is the link to the GRANT TSQL command.  I do not see any syntax like you are trying.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx

```
TO 'drupal'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Drup@l';
```

First, it should be `[drupal@localhost]`.  Second, I never seen the `IDENTIFIED BY` clause.  Where are you getting that information from?

3 - Here is a quick TSQL script that creates a badly named database and user.  If possible, change the name of the database and user.

Also, if you are granting permissions at the table level other than db_owner (very granular and a-lot of maintenance), then create an user defined database role.  Add securables to the role and add your user to the role.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187936.aspx

Sample code.

```
-- Create new database
create database [abc-123]
go

-- Use new database
use [abc-123];
go

-- Create table from sample data
select 
       [BusinessEntityID]
      ,[PersonType]
      ,[NameStyle]
      ,[Title]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[MiddleName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[Suffix]
      ,[EmailPromotion]
      , cast([AdditionalContactInfo] as varchar(max)) 
        as [AdditionalContactInfoTxt]
      , cast([Demographics] as varchar(max)) 
        as [DemographicsTxt]
      ,[rowguid]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
into 
      [abc-123].[dbo].[emp]
from 
      AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person;

-- Create a login
CREATE LOGIN [drupal@localhost] WITH PASSWORD=N'Ja08n13$', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[abc-123]
GO

-- Create a user
CREATE USER [drupal@localhost] FOR LOGIN [drupal@localhost] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

-- Add to database owner role 
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', [drupal@localhost]
GO
```

Output with user in db_owner group.

[image]

Comment: GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER ON abc-xyz.*  TO 'drupal'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Drup@l'; I am doing like this

Comment: Change abc-xyz.* to ALL.

Comment: @CRAFTY, if you use without `schema [dbo]` name, it will give `Invalid object name` error.

Comment: Why not add them to the dbo_owner group?

Comment: Posted sample code.  I leave creating a user defined role up to you.  I hope this helps.  J

Answer (score 6):

Use Back Quote for the DB name

```
select * from `abc-123`.emp;
```

or, select the existing database with a USE statement and run the query.

```
USE `abc-123`;
select * from emp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `[]` round the database name:

```
SELECT * FROM [abc-123].[dbo].emp;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM [abc-123].dbo.emp;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

if you are using databasename with table name then suppose to specify the `schema` name also.

```
select * from [abc-123].dbo.emp
```