# Hyphen not handled in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to fetch data from two different database on different server. Server name has hyphen `"-"`. So SQL is giving error as

```
"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".
```

Query used:

```
 SELECT * FROM [SERVER2NAME].[THEDB].[THEOWNER].[THETABLE]
```

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00933_sql_command_ended.htm

Comment: The issue is not hyphen as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995394/can-i-give-sql-server-database-name-with-hyphen-like-abc-123

Comment: `"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"` I just don't understand why do you use `mysql` tag when the error message is from an `oracle` database?

Comment: You tag MySQL, have SQL Server syntax, and an Oracle error message...

Comment: You say the server name has a hyphen, but your code has no hyphen in it.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle uses double quotes **"**

```
SELECT * FROM "SERVER2NAME"."THEDB"."THEOWNER"."THETABLE"
```

MySQL uses backticks **`**

```
SELECT * FROM `SERVER2NAME`.`THEDB`.`THEOWNER`.`THETABLE`
```

Comment: OP's error message clearly shows that the database is `oracle`. It is not valid syntax in Oracle.

Comment: Besides, are square brackets valid in MySQL?

Comment: @DanSin As I said, it is an **invalid syntax in Oracle**.

Answer (score 2):

you can use punctuation, white space, international characters, and SQL reserved words if you use delimited identifiers:

```
SELECT * FROM  `SERVER2NAME`.[THEDB].[THEOWNER].[THETABLE];
```

In MySQL, use the back-ticks. In standard SQL, use double-quotes.

Or if you use MySQL you can set the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode:

```
SET SQL_MODE = ANSI_QUOTES;
SELECT * FROM "SERVER2NAME.THEDB.THEOWNER.THETABLE";
```

Comment: OP's error message clearly shows that the database is `oracle`. It is not valid syntax in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

The `ORA` error clearly shows you are using Oracle database.

> SELECT * FROM [SERVER2NAME].[THEDB].[THEOWNER].[THETABLE]

That is an **invalid syntax** in Oracle.

If you want to connect between two databases, you would need to create a **database link** and have an entry in the **tnsnames.ora** file.

For example,

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK remotedb CONNECT TO scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger USING 'tns_conn_str';
```

Once database link is created, use it in your FROM clause:

```
SELECT * FROM schema.table@remotedb;
```

If you just want to connect to the database remotely using a **client** like **SQL*Plus** or **SQL Developer**, you just need to have the connection details:

For example, to connect using **SQL*Plus**:

```
sqlplus username/password@hostname:post_number/service_name
```