# SQL query with object name having illegal character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy data from SQL Server A to SQL Server B; so I have query statement like:

```
INSERT INTO ServerA_Name.db_name.table_name 
SELECT * FROM ServerB_Name.db_name.table_name where date >= GETDATE()
```

However the ServerA' name has a illegal character: '-' (ex: A-01) and I can't change the ServerA' name since it would cause other potential problem. So I got the: Incorrect syntax near '-'. error.... Is there a good way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you  not put the table names in double quotes?

Comment: Put the table or column name is square brackets.  But I don't see dash being used anywhere in your query.

Comment: hi jones321, you may want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20995483/4648586) first, it may be a good reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can I give SQL Server database name with hyphen like abc-123?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995394/can-i-give-sql-server-database-name-with-hyphen-like-abc-123)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Server A's name contained an illegal character (which I don't see one here in your case) you would need to place that server's name into square brackets, such as:

```
INSERT INTO [ServerA_Name].db_name.table_name
```

Square brackets in SQL server act as quotes and allow you to use special (or illegal) characters or spaces.